# Near smart-contract obscure instructions in the documentation

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, nearprotocol

example from documentation: https://docs.near.org/tutorials/examples/escrow

Here is the complete sequence of steps to run the example from the readme.md file:
https://github.com/near-examples/escrow-js

1. Login to your NEAR account

```
near login
```

2. Create sub accounts for deploying the contracts

```
near create-account --accountId <your-escrow-testnet-account-id> --masterAccount <your-testnet-account-id> --initialBalance <your-escrow-testnet-account-balance>
```

```
near create-account --accountId <your-assets-testnet-account-id> --masterAccount <your-testnet-account-id> --initialBalance <your-assets-testnet-account-balance>
```

**I replace:**

```
<your-testnet-account-id> : gettherefast.testnet
<your-escrow-testnet-account-id> : escrow.gettherefast.testnet
<your-assets-testnet-account-id> : assets.gettherefast.testnet
```

3. Deploy the Contracts

```
near deploy --wasmFile build/escrow.wasm --accountId <your-escrow-testnet-account-id>
```

```
near deploy --wasmFile build/assets.wasm --accountId <your-assets-testnet-account-id>
```

4. Initialize the Assets Contract

```bash
near call <your-assets-testnet-account-id> init '{"owner_id": "<your-asset-owner-account-id>", "total_supply": "1000", "escrow_contract_id": "<your-escrow-testnet-account-id>", "asset_price": "100000000000000000000000"}' --accountId <your-assets-testnet-account-id>
```

**There is some new account that I don't know anything about:**

```
   <your-asset-owner-account-id>
```

5. Perform a Purchase on Escrow

```
near call <your-escrow-testnet-account-id> purchase_in_escrow '{"seller_account_id": "<your-asset-owner-account-id>", "asset_contract_id ": "<your-assets-testnet-account-id>"}' --accountId <your-buyer-account-id> --amount 0.11 --gas=300000000000000
```

**and one more**

```
<your-buyer-account-id>
```

6. Check the Balance of the Buyer Account

```
      near view <your-assets-testnet-account-id> get_account_assets '{"account_id": "<your-buyer-account-id>"}'
```

**and one more**

```
near state <seller-account-id>
```

7. Approve the Purchase

```
near call <your-escrow-testnet-account-id> approve_purchase '{}' --accountId <your-buyer-account-id>
```

**Question: What to put in their place:**

```
<your-asset-owner-account-id>
<your-buyer-account-id> 
<seller-account-id>
```

I have no thoughts on this.
I have 3 accounts, but I need 6.

Comment: You can create more accounts needed for the example.

Answer (score 1):

The README could have been a little more explicit. I have updated it in the repository and will update the documentation in a brief moment as well.

As for what to do with these other accounts:

You actually only need two other accounts, namely:

- `<your-asset-owner-account-id>` that holds all the desired assets or assets for sale
- `<your-buyer-account-id>` which is the account seeking to purchase assets from the asset holder for some $NEAR.

I suggest you make sub accounts for each of these. I would call them something like `asset-seller.gettherefast.testnet` and `asset-buyer.gettherefast.testnet`.

As for `<seller-account-id>`, this is equal to `<your-asset-owner-account-id>` in this README example. So I have substituted this for `<your-asset-owner-account-id>`.